# Refresh java program with Button

Tags: java, swing, button, refresh, listener

I am trying to make a refresh button that will essentially restart the program when ever I click the button. I don't know how I should go about doing this.

I've place the Graphical User Interface i decided to use do complete this action. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

```
package pdfView;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class View extends JFrame {
    public View() {
        super("PDF Viewer");
        setLookAndFeel();
        setSize(500, 125);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout();
        setLayout(flo);
        JTextField Search = new JTextField ("Search", 29);
        JButton Search1 = new JButton("Search");
        //this is where i have the button 
        JButton ReFresh = new JButton("ReFresh");
        add(Search);
        add(Search1);
        add(ReFresh);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setLookAndFeel() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                    "com.sun.java.squing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel"
                    );
        } catch (Exception exc){

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        View pdf = new View();
    }

}
```

Comment: You'll want to use an event handler to execute code when your button is clicked.  Then you can execute your refresh code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by refresh or restart?

Do you mean:

1. Let the application be as it is, just update what it's showing?
2. Really restart the application?

### Updating what the application is showing

You first need to decide what actually should cause your application to refresh. You already talked about a Button. The mechanism for activating something like a button is called `Action`. You can do that stuff manually, using an `ActionListener`, or you could extend `AbstractAction`, which is what I recommend. Extending `AbstractAction` allows you to use the same logical action something in more than one location on the UI. Look at typical applications, they offer Cut/Copy/Paste through menu, toolbar, popupmenu and keyboard shortcuts. The simplest way to achieve this in Java is using `Action` by extending `AbstractAction`.

The methods you need to call to update your application are `invalidate()`, `validate()` or `repaint()`.

### Restarting an application

So you want to run through `main()` again? That should actually not be required, unless you have an application that supports updating itself. Even then it can sometimes be avoided by smart usage of a `ClassLoader`.

### Some more notes on your code

#### Usage by extension anti-pattern

I wouldn't extend `JFrame` just to display a window on the screen. Usage by extension is an anti-pattern. You don't need to extend `JFrame` to get a `JFrame` displayed on the screen and do what you want.

#### Referring static members

I would refer to constants via their original declaration. I.e. I'd refer to `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` via `WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`, not `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`.

#### Typo

You have a typo in your `UIManager.setLookAndFeel()` code. Search for `swing` and you will see the typo.

#### Exception information

You might actually want to print the exception to `stderr` using `exc.printStackTrace()` instead of ignoring it completely, because when you have a typo in the LaF class name, as you do, and you don't print the exception, you might actually not come to know what's going wrong.

#### Sequence of widget construction and `UIManager.setLookAndFeel()`

The sequence of `UIManager.setLookAndFeel()` and the effective `new JFrame()` via `super(...)` does not guarantee you that the whole UI will be in Nimbus, parts of it might still be in Metal. I recommend to set the LaF before even constructing the first widget, to be on the safe side. As far as I remember, it's not guaranteed that changing the LaF after component construction has an effect, unless you tell the UIManager to update the LaF. See also this quote from the documentation of `UIManager`:

> Once the look and feel has been changed it is imperative to invoke updateUI on all JComponents. The method SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(java.awt.Component) makes it easy to apply updateUI to a containment hierarchy. Refer to it for details. The exact behavior of not invoking updateUI after changing the look and feel is unspecified. It is very possible to receive unexpected exceptions, painting problems, or worse.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html

### `setSize()` vs. `pack()` with a little help of `Insets` and `Border`

Instead of setting the size manually, you might want to play with `Insets` or `Border` and `JFrame.pack()` in order to get a decent layout of your window. Setting the size manually assumes that you know a lot about the screen resolution and the font size of the user.
The `pack()` method performs automatic size calculation based on the contents. `Insets` and `Border` allow you to create some space and borders, even with some designs or labels, around components so they wouldn't be cramped tightly in a window but be nicely spaced.

Comment: Thank you for all the useful information. This helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to assign an [actionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) to the `ReFresh` Jbutton.

You can either implement the interface ActionListener to the class, and override the actionPerformed() method like this

```
public class View extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private JButton ReFresh;

public View() {
    super("PDF Viewer");
    setLookAndFeel();
    setSize(500, 125);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout();
    setLayout(flo);
    JTextField Search = new JTextField ("Search", 29);
    JButton Search1 = new JButton("Search");
    //this is where i have the button 
    ReFresh = new JButton("ReFresh");
    ReFresh.addActionListener(this);
    add(Search);
    add(Search1);
    add(ReFresh);

    setVisible(true);
}

private void setLookAndFeel() { //right way for nimbus: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html
   try {
        for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
             if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                  UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                  break;
             }
         }
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.equals(ReFresh))
    {
        super.repaint();
    }
}}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    View pdf = new View();
}
```

Or you can do inline assignment to addActionListener, like this

```
ReFresh.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                super.repaint();
            }
        });
```

You can try these methods to refresh/reload the JFrame,

```
invalidate();
validate();
repaint();
```

you can also use `dispose();` and then `new View();` to create the new JFrame, but in this sequence it will close the window and create new one.

or you can even try `setVisible(false);` then `setVisible(true);`

I recommend the first 3.

Comment: Thank you I have had a lot of trouble understanding action listeners and this helped a lot. :)